# How to increase index within a loop & stop enumerating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop

I've ran into a situation where I need a loop, but the code below returns only the very last index value. I need it to return the next value and stop enumerating. To explain better, say I have numbers 0-10, when pressing a button I need the index to increase by one. Now say I keep pressing this button until the index reaches 10, on the next press, the index needs to be back at zero (aka cycle through.)

Any help would be appreciated & I will most definitely accept the best answer.

Thanks in advance!

```
//grabs current index in a scrollview
long long currentSelectedIndex = [preview.swipeView currentIndex];
long long totalNumberOfAvailableSlots = [preview.swipeView indexTotal]; //index total is never an absolute value

@autoreleasepool {
    //currentSelectedIndex is supposed/always to be zero on first run
    for (int i; = (int)currentSelectedIndex; i <= totalNumberOfAvailableSlots; i++){
        NSLog(@"loop: %d", i);
        if (i == totalNumberOfAvailableSlots){
            i = -1;
            [preview.swipeView scrollToIndex:i]; //this will cause [preview.swipeView currentIndex] to be updated with "i" value.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: calling `break;` when you have found the value you want will exit the for loop.

Comment: Where's your button handler method? What does the posted code have to do with the button press?

Comment: @joels I'm not looking for a specific value as "totalNumberOfAvailableSlots" is subject to change. If I break; above the if statement, "i" will always return 0.

Comment: @CokePokes you're absolutely right.  Could you give us more info as to what you are trying to accomplish?  From your code it looks like you want to swipe through content of a swipeview.

Comment: Okay, it's really difficult to explain so bear with me here. I'm just trying to get the current index of a swipeview and scroll to the next index, but when making it to the end of the index, cycle back to zero.

Comment: Can you confirm that your for loop `i` variable is initially set to 0? `for (int i = 0; i <= totalNumberOfAvailableSlots; i++)`

Comment: @joels Yes it definitely is.

Comment: do your `currentSelectedIndex` and `totalNumberOfAvailableSlots` get assigned their proper respective value?

Comment: I'll also mention, a for loop iterate very rapidly.  The user will likely not see the behaviour you are intending.  For a scenario like this, I'd suggest making a timer that fires a method every, say 3 seconds.  And in that method, you simply scroll to the next index, if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, the behaviour you seem to be after is to automatically swipe through the contents of swipeView.

Make a timer which calls the `swipeToNext` method:

`myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: target:self selector:@selector(swipeToNext) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

Then handle the swipe:

`- (void)swipeToNext {
   if ([preview.swipeView currentIndex] < [preview.swipeView indexTotal]) {
      //Can swipe forward
      [preview.swipeView scrollToIndex:[preview.swipeView currentIndex]+1];
   } else {
     //At last index.  Need to go to first.
     [preview.swipeView scrollToIndex:0];
   } 
}`

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need `currentSelectedIndex` to go through this repeating sequence 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 1, ...

within `formLoad` you need to initialise your counter

```
 currentSelectedIndex = 0
```

within the button pressed method, increment the counter - but using the modulo operator to return the remainder - in this case of dividing by 11

```
currentSelectedIndex = (currentSelectedIndex + 1) % 11
```

in general, you can make a sequence of 0...n like this

```
currentSelectedIndex = (currentSelectedIndex + 1) % (n + 1)
```